# is my deduction correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

let be the power series

$$ f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^{n}}{\zeta (n+1) n!} $$

then we know that the Riemann zeta function tends to 1 as n tends to infinty so our initial series

will be very similar to  $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^{n}}{n!}=exp(-x) $$

therefero f(x) will tend to 0 for big 'x'

is my argument correct

Comment: What is the meaning of "will be very similar" ?

Comment: $$ f(x)\approx exp(-x) $$  for big 'x'

Comment: your argument is incorrect generally speaking as for example with $a_n=1+n!/(3n)! \to 1$ it is very to easy to see that if $f(x)=\sum a_n(-x)^n/n!$  then $f(x)-e^{-x}$ is an entire function of order $1/3$ which means that it will be highly unbounded on any ray so in particular $\limsup_{x \to \infty}|f(x)| =\infty$; here of course $\zeta(n)-1 \sim 2^{-n}$ so the result claimed may hold but it requires proof and I do not think it is trivial

Comment: the fundamental issue here and in similar problems where one tries to analyze $\sum a_n x^n/n!$ with $a_n$ known and "nice" is that although $\sum x^n/n! \to 0, x \to -\infty$ quite fast in $x$ the (absolute values of the ) partial sums actually are huge to start with getting up to the size $e^{|x|}$ at $n = [|x]]$ or so so any small deviations like the one above where $a_n=1+$ very small can throw everything in disarray and the result may become big as for the example above with $a_n=1+n!/(3n)!$ where $\limsup_{x \to -\infty}|f(x)|=\infty$